# When I clean Xcode DerivedData I can't run my app in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

In Xcode 6.0.1,I have to delete all my data in DerivedData,then I run my app,it builds successfully but I can't run it on the iOS Simulator iPhone 5.
Xcode warning :

> Invalid or missing Program/ProgramArguments

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: no error log. Xcode show me a alert window.

Comment: try to once quit Xcode and reopen then run again

Comment: I have already reboot my mac pro...but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you build another project?

Comment: Yes, I build a new empty project and run it succussfully in iOS Simulator. And I git clone a new copy of my project but it still can't run in Simulator.

Comment: YOU FIND ANY SOlution for this? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue when i migrated my project from xcode 6.4 to xcode 7 beta 6.
To solve this issue, you have to :
From top menu options GOTO,
xcode -> Preferences (cmd + ,) -> Locations
select the command line tool to your current version.

Now run your app, it should work fine.

Comment: For me, the solution was to change the location for the derived data. Normally I have it on a RAM-disk for performance, but be setting it to default, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

One of the following worked for me:

- cleaning project (Product/Clean)
- cleaning derived data (Window/Projects)
- reopening XCode and the project
- removing the scheme and re-creating it (Product/Scheme/Manage Schemes)
- changing location of Derived Data (XCode/Preferences/Locations, changing Derived Data to: Relative)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and noticed that Xcode created few build directories in different places all of a sudden.

So i went to build setting and revisited all build locations, quit Xcode, deleted all build locations directories, started XCode, cleaned build, revisited again and this fixed the issue.

Not sure what caused it at the 1st place though:)

Comment: where is build location ?