# Invalid or missing Program/ProgramArguments? No solution found

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having a very hard time trying to solve this annoying issue.
I created a COCOA static library in XCode that worked flawlessly until some days ago. Now, when i try to TEST it, i receive the following error:

"Invalid or missing Program/ProgramArguments".

I already tried to fix this problem performing the operations pointed out here

[Invalid or missing Program/ProgramArguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165306/invalid-or-missing-program-programarguments)

and here

[When I clean Xcode DerivedData I can't run my app in iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335145/when-i-clean-xcode-deriveddata-i-cant-run-my-app-in-ios-simulator)

without any success (XCode 7.2).

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

solution: I updated from XCode 7.2 to XCode 7.3 and suddenly everything started to work fine again.